# How to inject material instance for specific objects?

Tags: python, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I am creating an addon that allows you to create multiple shader based section planes. It was quite easy when I dealt with it on per material basis. Now I'm trying to do per Object basis. Now each section plane has its own list of objects that it affects. This creates two problems:

- One is that I need to break instancing and create a single user material so that other objects with the same material are not affected. This is undesirable for me as I want the user to still be able to change the material globally and not manually for each new material
- The second is keeping track of the materials. Each section plane can have multiple objects which means I cannot have only two material instances (one with and one without my node group). This can create a real mess in larger scene as I need to create a new single user material for each material within the object (because some contain only one node group, some none and some more)

For illustration:

[image][image]

These two section planes should affect each their own group of objects. local_1 should affect pinkBox object and local_2 should affect greenBox & pinkBox objects. There is also third object in the scene called pinkSphere that is not affected by any section plane but uses the same material instance as pinkBox.

[image]
This is what the material should behave like for pinkBox. Notice that I still want to keep the instance of 'pinkMat' and just inject the two node group at the end.

[image]
This is what it should behave like for pinkSphere which is not affected by any section plane.

I am looking for an easy way out of this. Basically what I need is to take whatever flows into the material output node, run it through my node groups and send it back to the material output. This way the instancing would not be broken and I wouldn't have to worry about tracking the materials. Is there any way to do injection like this? If not can you advise me the best way to do this without completely overflowing the blender file with unnecessary materials?

Comment: Could you please add some illustration of that? Injecting some group, node tree part, in another one is possible, though, hard to have a good idea of what you want without some example(s).

Comment: I updated the post with some screenshots. Hopefully it'll be clearer what I try to achieve

Comment: If the material that the user should be still able to modify is not itself a node group (and the user should know that), I don't see how this could be possible.